# How to use ffmpeg with drawtext and a emoji TTF

Tags: video, ffmpeg, truetype

I'm trying to overlay some text emoticons on top of a video using ffmpeg.. This works fine for normal TTF's e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf drawtext="Arial.ttf: text='YENTL  Bresseleers ': fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h-line_h)/2" -codec:a copy output.mp4 -y
```

I can use the [OpenSansEmoji](https://github.com/MorbZ/OpenSansEmoji) font which gets me closer to what I need..

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf drawtext="OpenSansEmoji.ttf.ttf: text='YENTL  Bresseleers ': fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h-line_h)/2" -codec:a copy output.mp4 -y`
```

However when I try with a TTF file with coloured emoji's like [emojione](https://github.com/Ranks/emojione) or [Noto Color Emoji](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#emoji-qaae-color) I get the below error:

```
[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0x7fd643700000] Could not set font size to 24 pixels: invalid module handle
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fd643608b80] Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args 'fontfile=AppleColorEmoji.ttf: text=YENTL  Bresseleers : fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h-line_h)/2'
Error opening filters!`
```

Any ideas?

Comment: At present (Jan-2016), regular font drawing engines do not support "colored characters" - there even isn't a definitive standard yet! All current implementations use private data in their fonts.  That's why any ol' font with 'regular' characters (i.e., an outline that gets filled with one (1) color) work but proprietary format bitmaps and outlines do not.

Comment: I was looking into this a bit further - it looks like libfreetype (the library which ffmpeg used to render text) has support for colored fonts since v2.5 - ref https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/freetype-announce/2013-06/msg00000.html & http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#FT_LOAD_COLOR

do you know what version ffmpeg uses and if it can be upgraded?

Comment: Doesn't work with ffmpeg compiled with libfreetype 2.6.2

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Try surrounding the text in single quotes and eliminate unnecessary spaces in the command.

Comment: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5777 -- emoji support still missing in ffmpeg

Answer (score 2):

For a dirty workaround one can manually adjust the emoji on top of a character like so

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i "https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/apple/237/smiling-face-with-sunglasses_1f60e.png" -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=24:24,format=argb,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5[ovrl],[0:v]drawtext=text='YENTL O Bresseleers':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:x='(w-text_w)/2':y='(h-text_h-line_h)/2'[text],[text][ovrl]overlay=main_w/2-46:main_h/2-20" -codec:a copy output.mp4 -y
```

and then remove the `,format=argb,colorchannelmixer=aa=0.5` part when the position is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, FFMPEG doesn't support emojis and some special characters,
i had the same issue,
and to solve that i took a different approach,
you can follow the same steps.

1. After adding your text, when you want to save it..
2. Convert those texts into the image
3. Add those images to FFMPEG with the help of the "Image overlay command".

i hope these steps help.