# FFMPEG drawtext with emoji

Tags: video, ffmpeg, emoji

Want to display a text with emojis  on a video or an image

```
drawtext=text='TextToDispley':fontfile=Roboto-Bold.ttf:fontcolor=white@0.9:fontsize=50:x=100:y=100:
```

But it doesn't work as expected.

[image: No Emojis]

Comment: Probably a duplicate of this:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880734/how-to-use-ffmpeg-with-drawtext-and-a-emoji-ttf

Also see this trac issue: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5777

Comment: Short answer: FFmpeg does not seem to be able to render emojis. If you really want to do this, you will have to work around the issue by rendering images of the emojis.

Answer (score 6):

As of the time of this answer (May 2018), FFmpeg does not support colored emojis.

See this FFmpeg trac issue, which frankly seems like it has been ignored for quite a while, so I wouldn't hold my breath that this will be supported in the near future:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5777

However, that doesn't make your task impossible. Just more complicated.

What I would do is instead of letting FFmpeg render the text and emojis on top of the image, is to create the text+emoji overlay as an image supporting transparency (e.g. png) with another program that is capable of doing so.

Then, use FFmpeg to render said image on top of your video.

However, I am not aware of any command line tool that would be easily capable of rendering text+emojis to an image. If anyone knows such a tool, I'll gladly edit my answer.
[FreeType](https://www.freetype.org/) itself does support rendering such an image, so you might want to try your luck writing a tool yourself using FreeType.